# ReactJS Hooks: Best practise to open and close multiple modals / dialogue boxes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am new to React and am picking up bits here and there as I'm trying to build this app. I have to create a page that opens a modal by clicking a button. In that modal there are 'back' and 'next' buttons and the user clicks one of these buttons to close the current modal and either open the next or previous modal in it's place. There are about 25 of them. I have included the base page here with the first 3 modal functions and all work fine but as you can see if I were to write all of them then it would be pretty ugly and just seems like there should be a neater way of doing things?

```
const BasicPage = (props) => {

    const [showDialogue1, setShowDialogue1] = useState(false);
    const onOpenDialogue1 = () => setShowDialogue1(true);
    const onCloseDialogue1 = () => setShowDialogue1(false);

    const [showDialogue2, setShowDialogue2] = useState(false);
    const onOpenDialogue2 = () => setShowDialogue2(true);
    const onCloseDialogue2 = () => setShowDialogue2(false);

    const [showDialogue3, setShowDialogue3] = useState(false);
    const onOpenDialogue3 = () => setShowDialogue3(true);
    const onCloseDialogue3 = () => setShowDialogue3(false);

    //and so on.....


return(


     <button
     onClick={onOpenDialogue1}

      >Show dialogue</button>

    

    {showDialogue1 ? <Dialogue1
        closeDialogue1={onCloseDialogue1}
        openDialogue2={onOpenDialogue2}

    /> : null}

    {showDialogue2 ? <Dialogue2
        closeDialogue2={onCloseDialogue2}
        openDialogue1={onOpenDialogue1}
        openDialogue3={onOpenDialogue3}

    /> : null}

    {showDialogue3 ? <Dialogue3
        closeDialogue3={onCloseDialogue3}
        openDialogue2={onOpenDialogue2}
        openDialogue4={onOpenDialogue4}

    /> : null}

   {/* and so on... */}


  )




}
export default BasicPage
```

And a modal would look like this:

```
 import React, {useState} from "react"
 import {Field, Form} from "react-jsonschema-form-validation";
 import Submit from "./components/Submit";
 import SelectError from "./components/SelectError";


const fieldName = 'referred';

const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: [
        fieldName
    ],
};
const Dialogue2 = (props) => {
        const closeDialogue2 = props.closeDialogue2;
        const openDialogue1 = props.openDialogue1;

        const openDialogue3 = props.openDialogue3;

        function Dialogue1(){
           openDialogue1();
           closeDialogue2();
        }

        function Dialogue3(){
           openDialogue3();
           closeDialogue2();
        }
        
       const [formData, setFormData] = useState();


       const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);


       const handleChange = (newData) => {
          setFormData(newData);
          setSuccess(false);
       };

       const handleSubmit = () => {

         setSuccess(true);
         console.log("Data submitted: " + formData[fieldName]);
         HospitalPage3();
       };

        return(

            <Form
              data={formData}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              schema={schema}
               <h1>Dialogue 2</h1>
               <p>Choose yes or no</p>
               <div>
                <Field type="radio"
                       name={fieldName}
                       id="yes"
                       value={"yes"}
                />
                <label htmlFor={"yes"}>Yes</label>

                <Field type="radio"
                       name={fieldName}
                       id="no"
                       value={"no"}
                />
                <label htmlFor={"no"}>No</label>


            </div>

               <button onClick={Dialogue1}/> BACK </button>
               <Submit 
                            onClick={onOpenError}
                            success={success}
                            text={'NEXT'}
               />
             </Form>
        )
    }
    export default Dialogue2


As I said it works fine but wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely a better way to do this, I think you are thinking about this wrong. Instead of opening and closing dialogues, just change the content of it. One thing you can't escape is listing the content that differentiates each dialogue. I'm showing you a simple example of how you should approach this.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Dialogue = ({ onClose, onNext, onBack, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
      <button onClick={onBack}> BACK </button>
      <button onClick={onNext}> NEXT </button>
      <button onClick={onClose}> CLOSE </button>  
    </>
  );
};

const dialogueContents = [
  <div>Some Text for D1</div>,
  <div>Some Text for D2</div>,
  <div>Some Text for D3</div>,
];

const BasicPage = (props) => {
  const [showDialogue, setShowDialogue] = useState(false);
  const [curDialogue, setCurDialogue] = useState(0);

  function handleNextDialogue() {
    setCurDialogue((prevDialogue) =>
      prevDialogue === dialogueContents.length - 1
        ? prevDialogue
        : prevDialogue + 1
    );
  }

  function handlePrevDialogue() {
    setCurDialogue((prevDialogue) =>
      prevDialogue === 0 ? 0 : prevDialogue - 1
    );
  }

  function handleCloseDialogue() {
    setShowDialogue(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowDialogue(true)}>Show dialogue</button>
      {showDialogue && (
        <Dialogue
          onNext={handleNextDialogue}
          onBack={handlePrevDialogue}
          onClose={handleCloseDialogue}
        >
          <h1>Dialogue{`${curDialogue}`}</h1>
          {dialogueContents[curDialogue]}
        </Dialogue>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default BasicPage;
```

I hope this gives you an idea. What you were trying to do is create a component for each dialogue separately. Unless each component is absolutely unique you don't need and should not do that. Instead find what things each dialogue has in common with one another and just replace the dynamic content of it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with this. This is very interesting and could be the right direction. Some of the dialogue boxes contain a basic form radio selection with validation so I'm going to have to work out how that would fit with this. Could it still work like this? I'll change my question with a better modal example...

Comment: I just want to say this worked! It too a while to wrestle in my form functionality but it's working great. Thank you very much for your help. I may even look semi professional when I present this to my client!